# Minimizing the combined neighbourhood of a path in a grid graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Given two vertices in a simple grid graph, how to find the path connecting them such that the combined neighbourhood of the vertices in the path is the smallest?

Consider this path between the vertices $1$ and $18$ in a $5\times5$ graph,
[image]

The neighbourhood graph of all the vertices in the path would give,[image]

The combined neighbourhood has a total of $13$ vertices.

For another path,

[image],

The combined neighbourhood would be,[image],

with a total of $14$ vertices.

I want to find a path that minimizes the number of vertices in the combined neighbourhood.

Comment: +1 for the clear question. We can always assume the starting point has coordinates $(0,0)$. Up to reflection symmetries and so on, we can also assume that the target point has coordinates $(m,n)$ for some $0 \leq n \leq m$. (Your first picture would be $m=3$ and $n=2$.) Suppose I first move to $(n,n)$ using right-up-right-...-up, and then move right-right-...-right to $(m,n)$. Do you think that is optimal? If yes, and you can prove it, then done. If no, can you give an example where that is not optimal?

Comment: Counter Example; Path from 1 to 22 in the 5x5 grid. Path you defined would be (1,6,7,12,17,22) with combined neighbourhood 14. A more optimal path would be (1,6,11,16.21,22) with combined neighbourhood 11.

Comment: Ok good, so boundary plays a role. Is your graph always a square or rectangle? Is the starting point always a corner point, or can start and stop be anywhere?

Comment: It can be square or rectangle; It can start and stop anywhere

Answer (score 4):

I think this question of OP might be more appropriate for a site with more graph theory people. Anyhow, the following seems to be a reasonable strategy: Given the graph `G`, try to construct an auxiliary graph `auxG`, with directed edges and weights, so that the available function `FindShortestPath` on `auxG` solves the problem that OP is asking on `G`. This will be useful if `auxG` can be constructed reasonably quickly and is of a similar size as `G`.

To see what I mean: If one moves right-right-right-right-... then one extends the combined neighborhood by 3 with each hop. If one moves right-up-right-up-... then on average one extends the not by 3+3 for each right-up-combination, but only by 5. So we could give weight 3 to each existing edge, and add diagonal edges with weight 5. In this case, `auxG` would have the same vertices as `G`, but more edges.

Because of the boundary, which is important in this problem, we have to do something similar near the boundary. I will not describe this in words and just drop the code:

```
(* original grid graph *)
n=10;
G=GridGraph[{n,n},VertexLabels->Automatic];
coords=Round[VertexCoordinates/.AbsoluteOptions[G,VertexCoordinates]];

(* neighborhood computations *)
nbh0[vertex_,dist_:1]:=VertexList[NeighborhoodGraph[G,vertex,dist]];
nbh0[vertex_,dist_,distmax_]:=Select[nbh0[vertex,dist],(Norm[coords[[vertex]]-coords[[#]],Infinity]<=distmax)&];
nbh[vertex_,x___]:=DeleteCases[nbh0[vertex,x],vertex];
sizenbh[vertices_]:=Length[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Map[nbh0,vertices]]]];

(* construct auxG *)
aux[from_,to_]:=sizenbh[FindShortestPath[G,from,to]]-sizenbh[{from}];
aux[from_]:=Map[{DirectedEdge[from,#],aux[from,#]}&,nbh[from,2,1]];
{auxedges,auxweights}=Transpose[Flatten[Map[aux,VertexList[G]],1]];
auxG=Graph[auxedges,EdgeWeight->auxweights,VertexLabels->Automatic];

(* find path *)
findPath[from_,to_]:=Flatten[Map[FindShortestPath[G,#[[1]],#[[2]]]&,
   Partition[FindShortestPath[auxG,from,to],2,1]]]//.{a___,b_,b_,c___}:>{a,b,c};
```

I stress that the construction of `auxG` is currently ad-hoc, I have not verified that it really generates the paths that OP wants.

Here is `G`:

[image]

Here is `auxG`. It has directed edges with weights. Away from the boundary, the weights are $3$ for horizontal or vertical hop, and $5$ for diagonal hop. Near the boundary it is a bit more complicated:

[image]

**Examples:** Corner to opposite corner:

```
p1 = findPath[1,100]
(* {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100} *)
```

Let us compare with the diagonal path:

```
p2 = {1,11,12,22,23,33,34,44,45,55,56,66,67,77,78,88,89,99,100};
```

They have equal neighborhood size:

```
Map[sizenbh,{p1,p2}]
(* {36,36} *)
```

The first example of OP is essentially

```
p3 = findPath[1,33]
(* {1,11,12,22,23,33} *)
```

which is the path OP has given. Finally, consider two paths from the left boundary to the right boundary:

```
p4=findPath[3,93]
(* {3,2,1,11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91,92,93} *)

p5=findPath[4,94]
(* {4,14,24,34,44,54,64,74,84,94} *)
```

Note that `p4` walks along the boundary, `p5` does not.

```
Map[sizenbh,{p4,p5}]
(* {26,30} *)
```

This shows that `p4` is indeed better than walking horizontally, which would have neighborhood size `30`. And `p5` is as good as walking along the boundary, which also has neighborhood size `30`.

Again, I do not claim that this always produces the paths that OP wants, but it seems to go in the right direction. It is based on calling `FindShortestPath` once (on `auxG`) so should be reasonably efficient.

Comment: This is very interesting and works really fast for large graphs. I've been looking for some counter examples but haven't been able to find any.

Comment: There are plenty counterexamples. For `5x5` grid and `{start,stop}=={2, 24}` it returns `{2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20, 19, 24}` which has total neighborhood `17`, but there are other six paths with total neighborhood `16`, for example: `{2, 3, 8, 9, 14, 15, 20, 25, 24}`.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Please `Quit[]` and try again. For `n=5`, with `findPath[2,24]` I get `{2,3,4,5,10,15,20,25,24}` with size $16$. But perhaps you find another counterexample (I am quite sure there is one).

Comment: Then there is something weird with your code. When you change `n` several times then it gives different results than on fresh kernel.

Comment: Dear @azerbajdzan, can you explain what you mean? Different `n` are supposed to give different results (obviously). For fixed `n`, if I restart several times, the result is always the same on my machine after restart (no randomness). I will remove the memoization for `aux` if that makes it easier...

Comment: Quit kernel. Then execute your definition code with `n=10`. Then execute `findPath[2, 24]`. Then execute definition code again with `n=5`. Then execute `findPath[2, 24]` and it returns `{2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20, 19, 24}`, not `{2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 24}` as it should.

Comment: And this is definitely counterexample: For `n=8` `findPath[1, 47]` returns `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 39, 47}` which has total neighborhood `27`, but there are two paths with `25`: `{{1,2,10,11,19,20,28,29,37,38,46,47}, {1,2,3,11,12,20,21,29,30,38,39,47}}`.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Since `n` is a global variable and the code used memoization, you had to restart each time before you changing `n`. Therefore, changing from `n=10` to `n=5` without restart (which is what you describe in your comment) would not work. In any case, I removed the memoization in the meantime, and it should now also work without restart.

Comment: The last example I gave  does not work even if I use fresh kernel.

Answer (score 2):

Minimal combined neighborhood is given by `cn`, in this case it is `15` for three different paths.

```
g = GridGraph[{5, 5}, VertexLabels -> Automatic];
{start, stop} = {7, 20};
paths = FindPath[g, start, stop, All, All];
len = Length /@ (AdjacencyList[g, #] & /@ paths);
cn = Min[len]
bestpaths = paths[[Flatten[Position[len, cn]]]];
HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph[#]] & /@ bestpaths
Clear[g, paths, len, bestpaths, start, stop, cn]

(* 15 *)
```

[image]

For `{start,stop}={2,22}`:

```
(* 12 *)
```

[image]

Comment: Take `{start,stop}={2,22}`. Your code produces `{2,7,12,17,22}`, but `{2,1,6,11,16,21,22}` is better.

Comment: This code only considers paths with length equal to that of the shortest path. In general it wont hold

Comment: @user293787: I modified my code, now it works correctly, but it is more or less a brute-force.

Comment: Hmmm...Its not even showing an output for 6x6 grid

Comment: Then instead of finding all possible paths find only shortest paths between start point and stop point plus shortest paths between start point and stop point that go through some boundary point of the graph and testing all possible boundary points of the graph.

Comment: Limiting the length of the paths at 2n where n is the grid length gives good results